# How do I associate a domain to a specific application url URL?

Tags: url, tomcat, dns

Suppose I own the domain mydomain.com and I have a web application on a server, at the URL http://99.99.99.99:1234/MyApplication/startpage.something

What I'd like to have is that if the user writes appserver.mydomain.com/ it goes to the application URL above, but the user still sees appserver.mydomain.com in the location bar (I used appserver instead of www to make the question more generic). I want also that if the user writes appserver.mydomain.com/app?q=120 it is like he typed http://99.99.99.99:1234/MyApplication/page?q=120, but the user **still sees** the URL as he typed it.

Until now (I'm using a cheap domain seller), I've been only able to have

http://appserver.mydomain.com:1234/MyApplication/startpage.something

or just http://appserver.mydomain.com but it remains only that in the url, even if there is a path or arguments in the URL.

I am mainly interested in Tomcat server, anyway any more generic istructions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this. When a URL says `http://something/`, all browsers connect to port 80. To connect to port 1234, you **must** have it in the URL: `http://something:1234/`.

What you can do is:

- create a URL redirect so that when a user connects to `http://something/` (port 80), the request is redirected to `http://something:1234/`. You could do this using .htaccess redirect rules in the document root of your `http://something/` site.
- in the document root of the `http://something:1234/` site, you could create a redirect rule that maps `/` to `/MyApplication/startpage.something`

With this solution, the user will see `http://something:1234/` in the address bar. In case you need it, there are various resources on the web (and here on SO) on .htaccess redirects.